# VBA Function Replace to Word 2010

Tags: string, vba, replace, ms-word

This is my first VBA attempt in Word. I want to Find multiple word matches and Replace All of them with the string I specify, preferably from an outside document. I have 1000 different words I want to replace with their 1000 different translations in a 200 page document. Now I'm stuck, because I can't get this function to work on my Word 2010 text. Is this code correct and how can I implement it?

```
Function R(StrFind As String, StrReplace As String)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrFind
    .Replacement.Text = StrReplace
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  MsgBox R("q", "a")
  MsgBox R("w", "a")
  MsgBox R("e", "a")
  MsgBox R("r", "a")
  MsgBox R("t", "a")
  MsgBox R("y", "a")
  ActiveDocument.UndoClear
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you using... a function...?

Comment: show the code you want to insert the shown one into

Comment: @DisplayName I have 200 page documents in English and I want to replace the most common English words with their translations in Bulgarian.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I can make it with an if else as well. Is my function the problem for it not working as a macro? The replace all "q","w","e","r","t","y" with "a" is just an example.

Comment: But why not a Sub?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns There is no reason really, I started coding VBA yesterday and I don't really know what I am doing. I can try writing it as a sub with a "if/else" and an array of words. Can't I run VBA functions like this in Word 2010? I understand a function like the ones in JavaScript and I just want to call it with different parameters.

Comment: To call a Function in Word, you will need a Sub, so it's just a matter of saving time. Functions are only useful if you are going to do several times the same "operation" but operators change. If you are going to do always the same (in this case, replace *something* by *other thing*) is not really worth it to make a function. Just make a Sub, and then run it with F5

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have 1000 different words I want to replace with their 1000 different translations in a 200 page document. To call each word and it's translation as different function parameters was what I thought. It would mean the operators change but it's the same operation.

Comment: Sorry, I explained poorly. Functions, indeed, are only useful if you are going to do several times the same "operation" but operators change and **you need a returning value**. If you don't need a returning value, a normal sub with parameters (because you have 1000 different words, you will need parameters), will work for you. In your case, you don't need a returning value, you just want the code to make some stuff for you, so you don't need a Function.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know it was that easy to point from one Sub to another Sub. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code to make it work. First, a method containing all the calls, and second a method executing the replace. Something like this:

```
Sub En2Bu
  R "q", "a"
  R "w", "a"
  R "e", "a"
  R "r", "a"
  R "t", "a"
  R "y", "a"
  ActiveDocument.UndoClear
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub R(StrFind As String, StrReplace As String)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Selection.Find ' Are you sure you want Selection here?
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrFind
    .Replacement.Text = StrReplace
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

Selection.Find is perhaps a mistake? Do you want to do it only in the selected text?

Comment: I made a mistake then. It should search in the entire 200 page document for matches not just a selection of text. Search for first word, replace it everywhere in the document with it's translation. Search for second word, replace it everywhere in the document with it's translation. Up to the final word and it's translation.